# Bulk files upload to ADLS gen 1

Tags: c#, .net, azure-data-lake

Is there anyway to upload or transform multiple files to adls in one attempt(Bulk Upload). If that is not possible any parallel processing feature available??.

Am looking for c# example.
Please advise..

Comment: Is that you want to know how to upload a directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload multiple files in one directory, we can use the method `BulkUpload` to implement bulk upload. Regarding how to use the method, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.datalake.store.adlsclient.bulkupload?view=azure-dotnet)

For example

1. [Create a service principal and configure permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.datalake.store.adlsclient.bulkupload?view=azure-dotnet)
2. Code

```
string TENANT = "";
            string CLIENTID = "";
            Uri ADL_TOKEN_AUDIENCE = new Uri(@"https://datalake.azure.net/");
            string secret_key = "";

            var adlServiceSettings = ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings.Azure;
            adlServiceSettings.TokenAudience = ADL_TOKEN_AUDIENCE;
            var adlCred = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(TENANT, CLIENTID, secret_key, adlServiceSettings);

            AdlsClient client = AdlsClient.CreateClient("<>.azuredatalakestore.net", adlCred);
```

But please note that the method has limits. it just can be used to upload files in the same directory one time and it will upload whole files in the directory. If you want to upload some files in one directory or files in different directories, pleas refer to the following code

```
static async  Task  Main(string[] args)
        {
            string TENANT = "";
            string CLIENTID = "";
            Uri ADL_TOKEN_AUDIENCE = new Uri(@"https://datalake.azure.net/");
            string secret_key = "";

            var adlServiceSettings = ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings.Azure;
            adlServiceSettings.TokenAudience = ADL_TOKEN_AUDIENCE;
            var adlCred = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(TENANT, CLIENTID, secret_key, adlServiceSettings);

            AdlsClient client = AdlsClient.CreateClient("<>.azuredatalakestore.net", adlCred);


            string[] filePaths = { };

            int count = 0;
            var tasks = new Queue<Task>();

            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                
                var fileName = "";
                // Add the upload task to the queue
                tasks.Enqueue(uplaodFile(client, filePath, fileName));
                count++;
            }

            // Run all the tasks asynchronously.
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);


        }

        private static async  Task uplaodFile(AdlsClient client, string filePath, string fileName)
        {
            using (var createStream = client.CreateFile(fileName, IfExists.Overwrite))
            {
                using (var fileStrem = File.OpenRead(filePath))
                {

                    await fileStrem.CopyToAsync(createStream);
                }
            }
        }
```